# Logarithm problem with two bases

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Given $$\log_x9+\log_9x=\dfrac{10}3.$$

How can I find the greatest value of $x$ that satisfies the equation above?

Answer (score 5):

**hint**: $a = \log_{9}x$, then you have a quadratic in $a$: $a + \dfrac{1}{a} = \dfrac{10}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\log_x9=t;\frac1{\log_x9}=\frac1t$ 
Solve $t+\frac1t=\frac{10}3$ 
$3t^2+3=10t$ 
$3t^2-10t+3=0$ 
$t=\frac{10\pm\sqrt{100-4.3.3}}{6}=3$ or $\frac13$.

So $\log_x9=3$ or $\frac13$ 
Solve them, you will not get a neat answer, but **an** *answer*.

Answer (score -1):

HINT:

$$\log_x9+\log_9x=\dfrac{10}3$$

Now by [Change of Base of Logarithm](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Change_of_Base_of_Logarithm) use $\log_x9=\dfrac{\log9}{\log x}=\dfrac1{\dfrac{\log x}{\log9}}=\dfrac1{\log_9x}$ to form a Quadratic equation in $\log_9x$

Now if $\log_9x=y,x=9^y>0$ for real finite $y$

Comment: @ZainPatel, Please find the original question, 
Nehorai had changed the semantics

Comment: Should it be $\log_x9 = \ldots = \frac{1}{\log_9x}$?

Comment: @ Lab, see where you are wrong: $\log_x9=\dfrac{\log 9}{log~x}$ not $\log_x9=\dfrac{\log x}{\log9}$.